# How to handle config files in PHP library

Tags: php, git, testing, config

I wrote a small library (https://github.com/dborsatto/php-giantbomb) that acts as a wrapper for an API. In order to work, the library needs 2 basic configuration options:

- An API key
- A file that describes the API options

What is the suggested way to handle these two files?

The API key is of course personal so it can't be added to the repository. But by doing so, I can't write a functional test for the library as a whole, thus limiting myself to only unit tests for the single parts. Do I give up the functional tests altogether or is there a way to make this work?

About the other config, basically it's a YAML file (https://github.com/dborsatto/php-giantbomb/blob/master/api_config.yml) that includes the base API endpoint, and configuration for each data repository. At the moment this is handled by a Config class that is decoupled in a way that the user must write glue code and inject data into the Config. This way it's easier to test, but as a whole I feel like it's creating a bigger disadvantage than just letting the Config class load the file, parse it and behave accordingly. What is the best way to do this? At the moment there are no tests in the repository, but I'm working on it (along with some code refactoring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to leave the configuration outside your library; I've done something similar for the Mandrill mailing service, where I left to the developer the management of the configuration (I was working in a Symfony 2 project). For me there is no `Config` class, just the service constructor that accepts the API key and an (optional) array of options:

```
public function __construct($api, $options = array())
{
    // My code
}
```

When I need to use my service inside the Symfony 2 application, I take the needed parameters and configuration from a place (Symfony's config files) external to my service; this way I can decouple the library from the configuration. Of course the service contructor throws an exception if the mandatory parameters are missing.

Comment: I wanted to make a Bundle over this library for easier use with Symfony, and in that case that's what I'd do. But in a Symfony environment it's easier because the configuration is centralized and it's actually Symfony that's in charge of the glue code. As a standalone library, I'm not sure what the best option would be. Maybe making the Config load a default configuration if none is provided?

Comment: I totally agree about the default configuration (if it's applicable: if I have to pass my API ID it should be a mantatory parameter without default). In general, I still think it's better to make your library receive the configuration from an external source: "To use my library you have to pass the parameters A, B and C" and you shouldn't care how or where those parameters are managed.

Comment: Instead of a bundle, have you considered about creating a simple Composer package? Just to not be strictly tied to Symfony ;)

Comment: I already created a Composer package for the library, and now I'll make a Symfony bundle that is built on top of it :)